# Add a customize control depending wich radio setting is checked

Tags: theme-development, customization

I am creating a theme for wordpress, right now I adding custom control to adapt my design into wordpress.

In one setting section, I would like to have 3 choices by radio buttons, but depending on which one is checked, show just below an input.

For now here what I have:

[image]

```
[dropdown]chose category
[radio]latest posts
[input]put id of the post
```

Here what i want:

```
[radio]display category
  if radio checked then display =>[dropdown]chose category
[radio]display latest
[radio]display personalize
  if radio checked then display => [input]put id of the post
```

etc..

Comment: What's the context, what have you done so far?

Comment: For now I added a dropdown to choose a category to display and a checkbox to display latest posts. It is a setting to choose what put in a slider. It is not possible to have a category and latest post at the same time. This is why i want a radio button to first chose if you want to display category or latest post and then chose wich category etc.

Comment: Since the radio button itself is not a customizer setting, you're looking at adding a piece of jquery for the buttons that in turn controls some css which of the three options to display.